# How can two r.v. be independent if one's density is a function of the other?

Tags: probability, independence, density-function, marginal-distribution

Suppose you have the following joint density function and marginal densities:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSFus.png)

Apparently, X and Y are independent, since their joint density is the product of their densities. However, I do not understand how this is possible, when the marginal density of X is a function of y.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something wrong here. $f_X(x)$ cannot depend on $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The product you are describing is, in fact, the chain rule:
$$ 
P(X,Y) = P(X \mid Y)P(Y)
$$

In this case, we have that the density associated with $Y$ is $f_Y(y) = e^{-y}$ while the density of the conditional distribution $X \mid Y$ is $f_{X \mid Y} = y^{-1}  e^{\frac{-x}{y}}$. This tells us that both $X$ and $Y$ are not independent for this joint model, because $P(X,Y) \neq P(X)P(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, how would you calculate the marginal density of X?

Comment: Using the law of total probability: $P(X \leq x) = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} f_{X,Y}(s,y) dy ds$ i.e. integrating with respect all possible values for $y$. This trick is called "marginalization" you can look it up at Wikipedia :). Note that the integral I wrote is the same as $p_{X}(x)=\int_{y} p_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) p_{Y}(y) \mathrm{d} y=\mathrm{E}_{Y}\left[p_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)\right]$

Comment: I have tried to do that, but there is not antiderivative if you integrate with respect to y. In addition, it seems that the density of Y is not a function of x, how can this be if Y and X are not independent?

Comment: The density of $Y$ shouldn't be a function of $x$ and the marginal density of $X$ doesn't need to have a closed-form. In fact, in most scenarios, one has to estimate densities numerically. The main issue here is to understand that in the image you posted, the referenced density is $f_{X \mid Y}$ and not $f_{X}$.

Comment: Understood. Your help is much appreciated :-)